# Using FFMPEG to rename MKV audio tracks for a more detailed description

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, matroska

I'd like to uniform the way audio tracks in MKV are named, with the number of channels, the codec and (if specified) the language of the audio track, something like:

- 5.1 AC3 Eng
- 5.1 DTS Eng
- 2.0 DTS Eng
- 5.1 DTS Ita
- 2.0 AC3 Ita

I read something about metadata attributes, but I can't find a way to automate this process for bulk converts.

Comment: AIUI, ffmpeg doesn't do in-place modification (updating/renaming) of metadata- one of the experts will no doubt confirm/refute! You might want to look into a different tool

Answer (score 0):

why not use mkvmerge? https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html

```
mkvmerge.exe --output E:\output.mkv --audio-tracks 1,2,3,4,5 --no-subtitles   
--no-chapters --language 0:und --default-track 0:yes --compression 0:none     
--language 1:eng --track-name "1:5.1 AC3 Eng" --default-track 1:yes --compression 1:none 
--language 2:eng --track-name "2:5.1 DTS Eng" --compression 2:none            
--language 3:eng --track-name "3:2.0 DTS Eng" --compression 3:none            
--language 4:ita --track-name "4:5.1 DTS Ita" --compression 4:none            
--language 5:ita --track-name "5:2.0 AC3 Ita" --compression 5:none "file1.mkv"  
--track-order 0:0,0:1,0:2,0:3,0:4,0:5 --probe-range-percentage 0.50
```